# SQL query to return result with different row

Tags: mysql, pivot

I am working with a database that has a table called 'order' that looks like the following.

```
id    day    item  
-------------------
11     1     apple    
11     3     banana  
11     4     berry  
22     1     coke  
22     3     pepsi  
33     2     chips  
33     4     salsa
```

I want mysql query output to look like the following:

```
id    1       2       3       4
------------------------------------
11    apple   null    banana   berry  
22    coke    null    pepsi    null  
33    null    chips   null     salsa
```

Is it possible to get such an output using mysql?

Comment: Please, tag your MySQL version.

Comment: This is PIVOT which is not supported by MySQL. You must emulate it.

Comment: Does the list of possible `day` column values is fixed and always equal to `1,2,3,4` ? Does `(id, day)` is defined as unique ?

Comment: Yes, day column values are always equal to 1,2,3,4 (or we know what the max value of day is, in this case 4) and (id, day) is unique

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `day` = 1 THEN item END) day_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `day` = 2 THEN item END) day_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `day` = 3 THEN item END) day_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `day` = 4 THEN item END) day_4
FROM source_table
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Posting a query only as an answer attracts a `LowQuality Post review` - IMHO - maybe, you could have added your comments to your answer.